# click function is not working and if i comment $('#tablenew').dataTable( {}); its working but i want datatable too

Tags: javascript, jquery

Click function is not working and if I comment  `$('#tablenew').dataTable({});` out, it's working, but I want this to work with datatable

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#tablenew').dataTable( {
        'bProcessing': false,
        'bServerSide': false,
        'sort': 'position',
        'sAjaxSource': 'springPaginationDataTables.web',
        'aoColumns': [
            { "mData": "UserId" },
            { "mData": "UserName" },
            { "mData": "UserStatus" },
            { "mData": "UserType" },
            { "mData": "AddedBy" },
            { "mData": "AddedDateTime" },
            { "mData": "UpdatedBy" },
            { "mData": "UpdatedDateTime" },
        ]
    }); 

    $('#tablenew').find('tr').live('click', function(){
        var row = $(this).find('td:first').text();
        alert('You clicked ' + row);
        /*   $("#userId").value(row);  */

        var url = '/paymentGateway/userInfoPage/'+row;
        $(location).attr('href',url);
    });

});
```

Comment: you could try with ".click(function ..." or ".on('click', function ..."

Comment: `$('#tablenew tr').on('click', function...`

Comment: Are you getting any console errors? What version of jQuery are you using? (because `live` was removed in version 1.9)

Comment: Did you try `$("#tablenew").on("click", "tr", function(){...});` ?

Comment: yes i have tried with onclick,.click n live function ,it works when i put $('#tablenew').dataTable( {....}); this function in comment...

Comment: If you're not getting any console errors, then maybe the `dataTable` plugin is registering it's own event handler for the `tr` elements and it's stopping event propagation. Try moving your click event handler `$('#tablenew').find('tr').live('click', function(){` above the plugin init code `$('#tablenew').dataTable({`

Comment: I would go with selector syntax and `#tablenew`'s parent.

Answer (score 1):

DataTables redraws the table structure (rows/cells) often. The `<tr>`'s that are initially getting the click event bound to them are being removed when the table redraws. You'll need to bind the events using event delegation on the table, instead of on the table rows.

This should work:

```
$('#tablenew').on('click', 'tr', function(){ ... });
```

Comment: i have tried this its not working click event is not generate